# Import CSV on Mac Neo4j: Couldn't load the external resource

Tags: import, neo4j, upload

I'm running in neo4j community edition hoping to upload a csv in my downloads folder

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM  "file:/Users/santouko/Downloads/neo4j_module_datasets/test.csv" as line
RETURN count(*);
```

However it return error msg where the path is different from the one I specified, any possible reasons?

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/Users/santokou/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/Users/santokou/Downloads/neo4j_module_datasets/test.csv
```

Comment: Try adding '/', "file://Users...." or "file:///Users....". The issue is that it takes your uri as relative path and not as absolute. Alternatively "file:../../../../Downloads/neo4j_module_datasets/test.csv" should also work.

Comment: none of this worked, the last one is returning a different error: URI is not hierarchical

Comment: Can you move your csv in `file:/Users/santokou/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import`? It's the default path for storing external csvs for security reasons. Then if you  call it by relative path it should work. If there is no "import" folder in that path, create one.

Comment: thanks Sevle. this indeed works. thinking of doing it too, was trying to make other path work but nvmd

Answer (score 0):

By default the LOAD CSV path is relative to the `import` directory of the Neo4j installation.

You can configure this by specifying a value for `dbms.directories.import` in `neo4j.conf`. See [this page](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#config_dbms.directories.import) or more info.